# Showing SVG tag with just styles inside another SVG tag

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg

I am trying to show `svg` element with just `style` tag inside another `svg` element as below.

```
<svg class="root-svg" width="500" height="200">
  <svg class="card-background" width="100%" height="100%" style="opacity: 0.79; box-sizing: border-box; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 15px; background: url(&quot;https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeaeGue0HlHLYRj5wYeUdYO1_geor9C3EvRh-nRzell6MbifcKrg&quot;) center center no-repeat;"> 
  </svg>
</svg>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/drboXa)

But content of inside `svg` is not showing up. But when I just show inside `svg` independently it shows up as excepted.
How do I show `svg` with just `style` tag inside another `svg`?

Comment: You can style like this only the root svg element

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the namespace for the inner svg ?

```
<svg class="root-svg" width="500" height="200" >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  class="card-background" width="100%" height="100%" style="opacity: 0.79; box-sizing: border-box; border-width: 2px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 15px; background: url(&quot;https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSeaeGue0HlHLYRj5wYeUdYO1_geor9C3EvRh-nRzell6MbifcKrg&quot;) center center no-repeat;"> 
</svg>
</svg>
```